# android.test.purchased displays as a white dialog with not buy or cancel button just name and price

Tags: in-app-purchase, play-billing-library, android-inapp-purchase

During the purchase flow, with ID: android.text.purchased, a plain white dialog box is displayed with only Sample Title and US$.99 at the top. No other buttons are present, e.g. no buy button.

I tried using the actual ID for the app on google play, and that worked fine.

But using stock tests:

android.test.item_unavailable  **Worked fine with an OK button displayed
**
android.test.canceled  Blank white dialog with Sample Title and US$.99 at the top but **no OK button**

android.test.refunded Blank white dialog with Sample Title and US$.99 at the top but **no OK button**

android.test.purchased Blank white dialog with Sample Title and US$.99 at the top but **no Buy or Cancel button**

````
```CURRENTLY RUNNING ```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you get a solution if yes, please share it here, I got the same issue